# Android SimpleCursorAdapter newView bindView error when Scrolling the listvew

Tags: android, android-listview

I display the information using `Listview`. However, I have two types of layout file depends on the information_type.

If information_type is `1`, I will use one layout file.And if information_type is `2`, I will use another layout file.When the `ListView` loaded, it will automatically go to bottom.

For example at the beginning, I have 40 list items.When the `ListView` is loaded, for the bottom 4-5 items, it displays using correct layout file.

However, when I scroll the `ListView` upper and then scroll down, the bottom 4-5 items changes their layout file.

Every time I scroll up and down, the list items(layout file) may changes usually.
Here is my code.

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

    private int layout;

    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.layout = layout;
    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        View v;

        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);           
        int col_type = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_MESSAGE_TYPE);
        String type = cursor.getString(col_type);
        Log.d(TAG, "in newView: type is:" + type);          
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            Log.d(TAG, "in newView: receive message");
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_chat_view_in, parent, false);
            holder.tv_title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.titleIn);
            holder.tv_message = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.messageIn);
            holder.tv_time = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.timeIn);
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "in newView: send message");
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_chat_view_out, parent, false);
            holder.tv_title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.titleOut);
            holder.tv_message = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.messageOut);
            holder.tv_time = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.timeOut);
        }
        v.setTag(holder);
        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c){
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

        int col_owner = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_OWNER_NAME);
        int col_target = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TARGET_NAME);
        int col_type = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MESSAGE_TYPE);
        int col_message = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MESSAGE_CONTENT);
        int col_time = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIME);

        String owner = c.getString(col_owner);
        String target = c.getString(col_target);
        String type = c.getString(col_type);
        String message = c.getString(col_message);
        String time = c.getString(col_time);


        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            holder.tv_title.setText("From " + target);
        }else{
            holder.tv_title.setText("To " + target);
        }
        holder.tv_message.setText(message);
        holder.tv_time.setText(time);
    }
    class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_title;
        TextView tv_message;
        TextView tv_time;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to override next methods:
public int getViewTypeCount() and public int getItemViewType(int position)